# Why is my second child process being hit before my first?

Tags: c, shell, command, pipe

Currently, I am trying to write a small shell that supports piping. In my function `execute(char** args, char** args2)` it takes two char arrays where each command is split by the delimiter `" "`. The first argument contains commands before the pipe (e.g `{ls, -l}` and the second argument, commands after the pipe (e.g `{wc}`).

In my `execute` function, however, the second child process `pid2` is run first and the first child `pid1` is never being hit.

I am not sure if I am missing anything essential to creating your own pipe commands in `C` and would really appreciate any help/advice I could get.

**Execute function:**

```
int execute(char** args, char** args2) {
    int des_p[2];
    pid_t pid1, pid2; 
    if(pipe(des_p) == -1) {
        perror("Pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid1 = fork();
    if(pid1 == 0) {
        printf("AT FIRST CHILD");
        dup2(des_p[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(des_p[0]);
        execvp(args[0], args);
        perror("execvp of of FIRST PROCESS failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    pid2 = fork();
    if(pid2 == 0) {
        printf("AT SECOND CHILD \n");
        dup2(des_p[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(des_p[1]);
        execvp(args2[0], args2);
        perror("execvp of SECOND PROCESS failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(des_p[0]);
    close(des_p[1]);
    wait(pid1);
    wait(pid2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you have multiple processes they can run in any order.

Comment: Try adding `\n` at the end of all your `printf()` calls. stdout is line buffered, so nothing is printed until a newline.

Comment: General rule of thumb when using a pipe with dup2: `close(fd[0]); dup2(fd[1], x); close(fd[1]);`.  That is, first close the end of the pipe you're not going to use.  Then dup to the end you are going to use.  Then close the dup'd end.  You aren't closing enough fds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first child is running, but you're not seeing the message because of stdio buffering. By default, stdout is line-buffered, so the buffer isn't flushed until you print a newline. You're printing a message without a newline, and then you're calling `execvp()` before you flush the buffer, so the buffer is never flushed and the message is never seen.

Change it to:

```
    printf("AT FIRST CHILD\n");
```